# How to import a python file to multiple files of a module with them not using the same variables?

Tags: python, import, shared-variable

I have a python file, let's say it is `common.py`

In this, I have some functions, and a variable which is needed for the functions:

```
TAG = '[TESTTAG]'

def myprint(obj):
    print(f'{TAG} {obj}')

def set_tag(out_tag):
    global TAG
    TAG = out_tag
```

I want to be able to use the `myprint()` function without having to pass the `TAG` parameter each time.
To set this `TAG`, I coded the `set_tag()` function

I have 2 other files, where I want to use the `myprint()` function, but with different tags:
use1.py

```
from common import *

set_tag('[USE1TAG]')

def testusage():
    myprint('First sentence')
    myprint('Second sentence')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testusage()
```

use2.py

```
from common import *
set_tag('[USE2TAG]')

def testusage2():
    myprint('Third sentence')
    myprint('Fourth sentence')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    testusage2()
```

When I run them individually, they produce the expected result.

But the problem is that I want to import both these files to a final file, and use their functions multiple times, with each using the `TAG`, that I previously set in their source files. This way the latest imported file changes the `TAG` to `[USE2TAG]`, and that will remain used.

combine.py

```
from use1 import testusage
from use2 import testusage2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testusage()
    testusage2()
    testusage()
    testusage2()
```

Output:

```
[USE2TAG] First sentence
[USE2TAG] Second sentence
[USE2TAG] Third sentence
[USE2TAG] Fourth sentence
[USE2TAG] First sentence
[USE2TAG] Second sentence
[USE2TAG] Third sentence
[USE2TAG] Fourth sentence
```

Expected result:

```
[USE1TAG] First sentence
[USE1TAG] Second sentence
[USE2TAG] Third sentence
[USE2TAG] Fourth sentence
[USE1TAG] First sentence
[USE1TAG] Second sentence
[USE2TAG] Third sentence
[USE2TAG] Fourth sentence
```

The problem is that they operate on the same `TAG` variable.
I know, that I could pass the `TAG` to the `myprint()` function each time, but I think that there must be a way to not use that.

I know that I could define the `myprint()` function to both the `use1.py` and the `use2.py`, but I would rather just import it as a "service", so I don't have to append it each time.

Is there a way to use the `myprint()` function in multiple files without passing the `TAG` parameter?

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to have a function that returns a correctly configured print function that you could then use. For this you could use a lambda. For example:

```
def _myprint(tag, obj):
    print(f'[{tag}] {obj}')

def get_myprint(tag):
    return lambda obj, tag=tag: _myprint(tag, obj)
```

And then where it's being used you can do something like:

```
print_a = get_myprint('a')
print_b = get_myprint('b')

print_a('test a')
print_b('test b')
```

Which gives

```
[a] test a
[b] test b
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your answer! It solves my problem in an elegant, python-ish way! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You should check out `functools.partial`, which is super helpful for this kind of thing. In the file where you define myprint, have a generic function defined:

```
def generic_myprint(tag, obj):
    print(f'{TAG} {obj}')
```

Then, in the files where you're importing myprint, have the following code:

```
from functools import partial
from common import generic_myprint
myprint = partial(generic_myprint, tag='[USE1TAG]')
```

Obviously, replace the `tag` argument for each file where you want a different value.

`functools.partial` takes a function with many arguments, and returns a new `partial` object, which behaves exactly the same way as the original function, but with one or more parameters "pre-loaded" as default values. In this case, `myprint` now needs only the `obj` parameter when called. `generic_myprint` accepted 2 arguments, but `myprint` only accepts 1.

In my opinion, this is more pythonic than using a `lambda` function, but your mileage may vary!

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html

Comment: Thank you! This is a good option to generate the function as well!